# How to browse files on device using bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I recently got my bluetooth between computer and phone to work well together, but now I need to browse files on my device... I found some older instructions here on askubuntu, that seem a little outdated.   So I want to ask if instructions  for fedora that I found googling, might be applicable for ubuntu 14.04 as well since the instructions are a bit more recent...

Is this combination of package installs sufficient to browse files on my device?

```
gvfs-obexftp
nautilus
bluez-gnome
```

I tried these instructions:

```
Create a folder in `/media/mountpoint with root rights
Install obexfs
pair the phone with the PC

Get the device MAC and mount it with obexfs:

sudo mkdir /media/mountpoint
sudo apt-get install obexfs
hcitool scan

Scanning ...

8F:77:17:77:44:16 My Android Phone

obexfs -b 8F:77:17:77:44:16 /mountpoint
```

To unmount the device:

```
fusermount -u /mountpoint
```

while I was able to mount the device, I couldn't actually and open the folder and browse files.  The computer stated that I need root user permissions...

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake.  My phone and my computer had the same exact user name "myuser"...  that caused my issues.  I changed the name of my phone, reboot phone and pc, now I can browse files and send files between devices no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal to browse files on your bluetooth device.
Bring up the terminal by Ctrl+Alt+t.

The `cd` command is used to change directory. The `ls` command is used to list files in current directory.

Removable devices are usually in the directory /media.
To change directory to /media, enter the following: `cd /media`, then use the `ls` command to list the content of the /media directory. You should find your device name - I'll call it "device_name" in the command - in this directory. If you do, type in `cd /device_name`. After this just type in `ls` to list the content of the directory.

A short-cut would be: `cd /media/device_name; ls`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way i can do Browse Files on Device via the gnome panel indicator using nautilius?  I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: If you found the directory where your phone is located, you should be able to find it using nautilus. Just go to the directory where your removable media is mounted. Please provide the directory if you found it.

Comment: no such directory... I am connected to my phone via bluetooth, sharing web connection and capable of sending files back and forth, but no such directory that you mentioned... I go to /media and only my DVD rom is recorgnized